# how to perform a SELECT Statement on a JSON column in mysql/mariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4

how to apply WHERE clause on JSON column to perform a SELECT query on a table which is having two columns (id Integer, collection JSON). I am trying to look for specific integers in the collection column, like 223447 or 235073.

| id | collection |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a:2:{i:0;i:223406;i:1;i:223447;} |
| 2 | a:4:{i:0;i:213513;i:1;i:58168;i:2;i:247337;i:3;i:235073;} |

I tried to query 223447 (MariaDB 10.4.31) with:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `wp_collection_data`
WHERE
    JSON_CONTAINS(id, '"223447"', '$.i');
```

and

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    `wp_collection_data`
WHERE 
    JSON_EXTRACT( id, '$.i' ) = 223447
```

and got:

```
Warning: #4038 Syntax error in JSON text in argument 1 to function 'json_contains' at position 1
```

I think the "a:2:" in front of the json is causing this issue.

Can I edit the where clause to use the mariadb JSON Functions?

Is it possible to query an integer by searching all integers between the characters ":" and ";"?

Comment: Probelm is - That is not JSON, its the output from a PHP [`serialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and neither MySQL or MariaDB have a way to access it directly. You will have to fetch the data into PHP and [`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it there

Comment: Please publish the table definition and the insert statements as text.

Comment: You can use this link to check if a string is a valid json or not https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Why not store the data normalized?

Comment: Don't JSON functions need to be told to look in the `collections` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection column does not contains a valid json.

here is a way to filter your data :

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `wp_collection_data`
WHERE
    collection like '%i:223447;%'
```